# Unity 3D Aerial movement and jumping problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## Aerial Movement Problem

I've followed a few tutorials and I've set up a decent base for a game, - basic player movement, entity animation, health, HUD UI, etc. - but I wanted to make the movement a bit smoother, less snappy, more physics-based, you get the gist. I made it a bit better and it definitely meets all the requirements for terrain-based movement (i.e: movement across physical surfaces - while the player is on the ground), but I want jumping to be a bit more dynamic, and I know what I want to do but I'm having trouble doing it.

---

### Here's the issue:

If the player moves (regardless of whether `sprintActive` is toggled or not) and they jump after moving, the player gains speed in the air *way* too fast, and they can't move in any direction other than forward (relative to their rotation).

### Here's the objective:

I set it up so the velocity is simply redirected to whatever direction is forward from the `playerRB`, but I think I would prefer if the velocity didn't immediately change direction, but rather gradually curve as the player tries to move a certain direction? I know I may be asking for a lot, but some advice on how to do this, or if I should try a different approach, would be *very much* appreciated.

---

#### Code used:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RFPSPlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedForce;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float diveForce;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.25f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    
    private Transform playerBody;
    private Rigidbody playerRB;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool sprintActive = false;
    private bool delay = false;
    private float lateralSpeed;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    
    float xMov, zMov;
    float xSpeed, zSpeed;
    
    IEnumerator DelayTimer(float duration)
    {
        delay = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        delay = false;
    }
    
    void Start()
    {
        playerBody = GetComponent<Transform>();
        playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        xMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
        zMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            sprintActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            sprintActive = false;
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            Movement(0, speedForce);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            Movement(0, -speedForce);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Movement(-speedForce, 0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Movement(speedForce, 0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if(delay == false)
            {
                if(isGrounded)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(DelayTimer(0.05f));
                    Jump(jumpForce);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        velocity = playerRB.velocity;

        lateralSpeed = new Vector2(playerRB.velocity.x, playerRB.velocity.z).magnitude;
        
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded)
        {
            velocity = new Vector3(
                xMov + (float) (playerRB.velocity.x * 0.90), 
                playerRB.velocity.y,
                zMov + (float) (playerRB.velocity.z * 0.90)
            );
        }
        else
        {
            velocity.x = (float) (playerBody.forward.x * lateralSpeed);
            velocity.y = playerRB.velocity.y;
            velocity.z = (float) (playerBody.forward.z * lateralSpeed);
        }

        playerBody.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, playerBody.eulerAngles.y, 0);

        playerRB.velocity = velocity;
    }

    void Movement(float xAmount, float zAmount)
    {
        if(sprintActive)
        {
            xSpeed = (float) (xAmount * 2);
            zSpeed = (float) (zAmount * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            xSpeed = xAmount;
            zSpeed = zAmount;
        }

        playerRB.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(xSpeed, 0, zSpeed), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
 
    void Jump(float yAmount)
    {
        playerRB.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(0, yAmount, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```